# Optimal loadout for Death Drop missions

Tags: rebel-galaxy

I have the second ship and a combination of scatter turrets, mining lasers, flak cannons, the long range broadsides (forget what they're called at the moment). Hull, shields, and deflector are all upgraded to Mk II as well. I have the second ship.

However, when I pick up the cargo for the Death Drop missions, a **ton** of smaller fighters, bombers, and gunships show up and surround you (maybe a corvette or 2? I don't remember seeing anything larger). I can take out a few fighters and bombers before my shields get absolutely devastated, I begin retreating, and eventually get destroyed.

I've got to be doing something wrong here. I'm assuming my loadout could also be to blame. Maybe my strategy is just plain wrong. The difficulty shows "Average" but it feels much harder than most. For now, I've just attempting these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these missions, it's not essential to fight all the craft that spawn when you pick up the package.  In fact, I'd suggest running like heck if you don't feel comfortable taking them down.

I tend to grab the package, and then boost as hard as I can towards whatever edge of the circle of crafts is directly in front of me.  If you use your deflectors, and follow a zig-zag pattern, you can effectively absorb a lot of fire.  However, you want to be moving away as fast as possible.

Heck, even if I feel like I can take down the swarm of craft, I'll still run out of the middle of them.  This is just so that I can strategically use my shields to block as much fire as possible, and I can also kite just the fastest ones to start with, while keeping the slower, larger craft out of range.

Once you're clear of the ships and any asteroid belts, you'll be able to jump to warp and set a course to the station to drop off the package.  From there on out, things are significantly easier.

I've found that the difficulty rating is often wrong for me - sometimes I've easily completed "very hard" missions, while I would struggle with things marked "easy" or "average."  There's a bit of your own strategy that comes into play.

Comment: Definitely agree on the difficulty being off, even within the same difficulty. Story mission that are average are much easier than side missions that are also average, in my opinion.

Comment: @DangerZone, I'd also suggest keeping in mind how much cash you can make vs how long a mission takes you - some of the missions are not so much hard as they just take forever, and that's bad for earning money.

Comment: Definitely! There are a ton of low risk missions I keep repeating because of this very reason. They might get boring, but hey, easy money.